# Is there a good way of generating sets like this, other than a purely algorithmic way?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let a "pair" be a pair of two boolean values, so $00$, $01$, $10$, or $11$.
If I am told to construct an ordered set of these pairs given these constraints (if possible):

- I am to use a set of which of the the four possible pairs I can use at each index, so one possible permutation for this constraint would be:
  "Element one can be $01$ or $11$, two can be $11$ or $01$ or $11$, three can $00$ or $10$, and four must be $11$".
- The first element of each pair is the opposite of the last element of the previous pair, so $00, 10, 11, 00, 01, 01, 00$ is valid while $00, 10, 01, 11, 10, 00, 11$ is not.

I can imagine a programmatic solution to this, simply starting with each pair and creating a tree-like structure out of branching off to each valid possibility for the next pair. However this seems "brute-force"-ish, and I'm wondering if there's some useful property of things that follow this pattern that could allow me to generate them rather than "elimate" invalid possibility from the solution set.

I'm honestly not sure what part of mathematics this falls under, so feel free to suggest or edit in a tag.

Comment: If you want only to generate such sequences then what is wrong with programmatic solution? Also, please describe your constraints more formally - it's unclear why the first element is 01 or 11. The sequence you consider valid contains (00, 01) which contradicts with your constraint.

Comment: @HEKTO That's just an example, the two constraints are unrelated. The possible values are independent information, taken as input. I'll make that more clear.